# How to change the text or background color for a specific link when i hover over?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 different links in my html and I want to change the text color of only one specific link when I hover over. The problem is that when I apply the css, it changes the color for all the links. Please help!

Comment: We need to see some code. Add a [mcve] to your question please.

Comment: Please study [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). In your case you need [id selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You should put different id to your component for example

```
<a id="link1"></a>
<a id="link2"></a>
```

Then in your css change by doing that :

```
#link1:hover {
   color: red
}

#link2:hover {
   color: green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append an unique [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) or [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) to the links in the html,then apply the css

```css
.link1:hover{
    color: red;
}
.link2:hover{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<a class="link1">link1</a>
<a class="link2">link2</a>
```

Comment: `Append an unique class or id` could you please explain the difference between class and id so that OP could **learn** from your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="link" ></a>

#link:hover {
   color: #F48832;
}
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you do so that OP can **learn** rather than just copy-paste your snippet.

Comment: This answer is incomplete - and someone else posted a more complete answer in the same spirit, I'm recommending deletion.

Comment: <a id="link1" >link1</a> <a id="link2" >link2</a>     and  in the css file  juste add :  #link1:hover {
   color: #F48832;
} #link2:hover {
   color: #F48832;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

You should add custom css class  to your specific link and that css class to add below css..

```css
.specific_link:hover{
    color: blue;
}

a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="specific_link">link1</a>
<a>link2</a>
<a >link3</a>
```

Comment: Instead of just `try this...` please answer the question in full by explaining exactly what you do so that OP could **learn**.